# Converting between recursive / indented tree data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

To represent a tree, for example:

- root

  - a

    - a.1
    - a.2
  - b

a, one might use the following data structure:

```swift
struct TreeNode {
    var name: String
    var children: [TreeNode] = []
}

var rootNode =
    TreeNode(name: "root", children: [
        TreeNode(name: "a", children: [
            TreeNode(name: "a.1"),
            TreeNode(name: "a.2"),
        ]),
        TreeNode(name: "b"),
    ])
```

b, alternatively an ordered list with an attribute for the indent could be used:

```swift
struct FlatTreeNode {
    var indent: Int
    var name: String
}

var tree = [
    FlatTreeNode(indent: 0, name: "root"),
    FlatTreeNode(indent: 1, name: "a"),
    FlatTreeNode(indent: 2, name: "a.1"),
    FlatTreeNode(indent: 2, name: "a.2"),
    FlatTreeNode(indent: 1, name: "b"),
]
```

Depending on what I want to do with the tree, I found one or the other form easier to work with.

I wondered:

- Are there well-known terms you would use to differentiate between a data structure like a) or b)? (something like `recursive` vs. `flat/indented` tree representation?)
- Is there a standard algorithm to convert between those two forms?

Comment: For your flat list, how would you attribute which node belongs to which parent? Is it by list order?

Comment: If it is by list order, you can generate it from the recursive structure via a preorder traversal of the tree :)

Comment: Yes, by the order of the list. How about the other direction? (which I found finicky to implement :)

Comment: You are looking for how to flatten and unflatten dicts

Comment: Hmm, I think you could write a recursive function starting at the root of the tree iterating through the list such that as long as the indent is exactly 1 more than the current indent, you would create child nodes. If the indent is greater than 1, you would call the recursive function on the rightmost child with the remainder of the list. If the indent is smaller than or equal to the current indent, it will return the current position in the list, such that the calling function can continue to iterate and generate said node's siblings

Comment: @RalfEbert, I created http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_datastructures from riffing on your question and my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On nomenclature, I am not aware of any standard description, but I would describe your first as a nested datastructure; the second as a list showing successive indentation.

Here's a Python program that:

1. Defines the first as nested nodes as 2-tuples of name followed by a list of its children (which can be an empty list denoting leaf items).
2. The second format is a list of 2-tuples whose first item is the indentation, second item a name.

The program converts both-ways and compares to show you can round-trip the conversions.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

def to_list(node, depth=0, flat=None):
    if flat is None:
        flat = []
    if node:
        flat.append((depth, node[0]))
    for child in node[1]:
        to_list(child, depth + 1, flat)
    return flat

def to_nest(lst, depth=0, level=None):
    if level is None:
        level = []
    while lst:
        d, name = lst[0]
        if d == depth:
            children = []
            level.append((name, children))
            lst.pop(0)
        elif d > depth:  # down
            to_nest(lst, d, children)
        elif d < depth:  # up
            return
    return level[0] if level else None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Start Nest format:')
    nest = ('root', [('a', [('a.1', []), ('a.2', [])]), ('b', [])])
    pp(nest, width=20)

    print('\n... To List format:')
    as_list = to_list(nest)
    pp(as_list, width=20)

    print('\n... To Nest format:')
    as_nest = to_nest(as_list)
    pp(as_nest, width=20)

    assert nest == as_nest
```

**Output:**

```
Start Nest format:
('root',
 [('a',
   [('a.1', []),
    ('a.2', [])]),
  ('b', [])])

... To List format:
[(0, 'root'),
 (1, 'a'),
 (2, 'a.1'),
 (2, 'a.2'),
 (1, 'b')]

... To Nest format:
('root',
 [('a',
   [('a.1', []),
    ('a.2', [])]),
  ('b', [])])
```

Of course, the datastructures could use namedtuples, but Ichose not to.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode, this should do the trick:

```
// Arguments flatTree and index mussed be passed by ref
Flatten(node, flatTree, index = 0, indent = 0){
    flatTree[index] = FlatTreeNode(node, indent)
    index += 1
    for child of node {
        Flatten(child, flatTree, index, indent+1)
    }
}

// Arguments flatTree and index mussed be passed by ref
Unflatten(flatTree, index = 0){
    indt = Indent(flatTree[index])
    node = TreeNode(flatTree[index])
    index += 1
    while index < len(flatTree) and Indent(flatTree[index]) > indt {
        child = Unflatten(flatTree, index)
        AddChild(node, child)
    }
    return node
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Swift version of `flatten` + `unflatten`:

```swift
import Foundation

public struct TreeNode<T: Equatable>: Equatable {
    var content: T
    var children: [TreeNode] = []
}

public struct IndentedTreeNode<T: Equatable>: Equatable {
    var indent: Int
    var content: T
}

public func flatten<T>(_ node: TreeNode<T>, indent: Int = 0) -> [IndentedTreeNode<T>] {
    [IndentedTreeNode(indent: indent, content: node.content)] + node.children.flatMap { flatten($0, indent: indent + 1) }
}

public func unflatten<T>(_ list: [IndentedTreeNode<T>]) -> TreeNode<T>? {
    guard let firstNode = list.first?.content else { return nil }
    let remainingNodes = list.dropFirst()

    var root = TreeNode(content: firstNode)
    var lastNodePath = IndexPath()

    for node in remainingNodes {
        let pathToNodeParent = lastNodePath.prefix(max(node.indent, 1) - 1)
        var children = root[pathToNodeParent].children
        children.append(TreeNode(content: node.content))
        root[pathToNodeParent].children = children
        lastNodePath = pathToNodeParent.appending(children.indices.last!)
    }

    return root
}

public extension TreeNode {

    subscript(indexPath: IndexPath) -> TreeNode {
        get {
            if indexPath.isEmpty {
                return self
            } else {
                return self.children[indexPath.first!][indexPath.dropFirst()]
            }
        }
        set {
            if indexPath.isEmpty {
                self = newValue
            } else {
                self.children[indexPath.first!][indexPath.dropFirst()] = newValue
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Swift package with unit tests: https://github.com/ralfebert/IndentedTree